# error running ios app blank screen on physical device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, flutter

Hey i'm trying to test a flutter mobile app for ios, it works fine on the emulator in the computer but when i try to run it on a physical iphone connecting the device to the mac i am having some problems. Xcode build finishes and i everything seems to work but when it launches the app it stays on blank screen and doesnt work.

From xcode i get this output:

```
    2021-02-26 16:42:08.238514+0100 Runner[3160:203962] fopen failed for data file: errno = 2 (No such file or directory)
2021-02-26 16:42:08.238569+0100 Runner[3160:203962] Errors found! Invalidating cache...
2021-02-26 16:42:08.261481+0100 Runner[3160:203961] [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Deletion failed, path = '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/~/Library/Caches' (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)
#0      _Directory._deleteSync (dart:io/directory_impl.dart:201)
#1      FileSystemEntity.deleteSync (dart:io/file_system_entity.dart:455)
#2      main (package:MyApp/main.dart:48)
```

Any idea what might be the problem?, since it works on emulator i guess there is some trouble with the mac or the iphone but i can't find what is wrong.

Comment: Have you tried to run `flutter clean` and build for iOS again?

Comment: i did and it didnt work, have you encountered a similar issue?

Comment: You seem to be deleting a file on app start but you don't have access to it. Probably because your apps path changed due to reinstall.